# References and auto_ptr

Tags: c++, reference, auto-ptr

If I have a auto_ptr I can pass it for a reference?Like:

```
auto_ptr<MyClass>Class(new MyClass);
void SetOponent(MyClass& oponent);
//So I pass SetOponent(Class)
```

And what is odd copy behavior of auto_ptrs?

Comment: not sure why this is community wiki...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, you would have to dereference it:

```
SetOponent( * Class )
```

As for the copying behaviour, I recommend you read a good book on C++, such as Effective C++ by Scott Meyers. The copying behaviour of auto_ptr is extremely un-intuitive and possibly beyond the scope of an SO answer. However, nothing ventured...

When an auto_ptr is copied, ownership is transferred from the original to the copy. For example:

```
auto_ptr <Foo> p1( new Foo );
```

at this point p1 owns the pointer to the Foo object.

```
auto_ptr <Foo> p2( p1 );
```

After the copy, p2 owns the pointer and **p1 is changed** so that it now holds a NULL pointer.  This is important, because copying occurs in lots of places in C++. You should never, for example, pass auto_ptrs by value to functions, or attempt to store them in standard library containers.

Comment: I thought you could pass an auto_ptr by value to a function if you wanted to pass ownership of the pointer to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The odd copy behavior is that you can't make a copy and still have the original.  Use `shared_ptr` (in boost:: or std::tr1::) for that.  This means you can't have an STL container of `auto_ptrs`, among other things.  `auto_ptr<>` is very useful for when you will have one copy of an object, with a limited lifetime.  If you copy to another `auto_ptr<>`, you lose the first.  If you pass out the pointers, you have an excellent chance of trying to use an object that's already been deleted.

You can call `SetOponent(*Class);` if you like, as that will pass the actual item (you pass objects, not pointers, to references).  If you pass to a pointer, you could call with `SetOpponent(Class.get())`.  You'll still have the problem that the MyClass will be deleted when Class goes out of scope.

Comment: You are not explain the main reason for auto_ptr<>. Which is to pass ownership. It is an explicit method (and thus implicitly self documenting) of ceding ownership of an object to another entity.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the main reason is to guarantee that something that is allocated will be deleted.  It does specify ownership, but most objects don't get their ownership transferred.  In my experience (which may not be typical), auto_ptrs are not copied.

Comment: In my experience auto_ptr<> usage is to provide a mechanism for the explicit transfer of ownership of a dynamically allocated objects from its creator to some other entity. If the entity accepts it takes ownership if not the object is de-allocated.

Comment: Then our experience differs.  Do you have any references (preferably from Stroustrup or a Committee member) about auto_ptr being primarily for transfer of ownership?

Comment: auto_ptr's responsibility is to ensure a newed object is deleted.  In so doing, it MUST transfer ownership when copied because otherwise an object could be deleted more than once, which is undefined behaviour.  With two auto_ptrs, when you say p1 = p2, the pointer in p1 is deleted, the pointer in p2 is put in p1 and the pointer in p2 becomes NULL.  When p1 is destructed, the pointer is deleted.  When p2 is destructed, NULL is deleted, which of course is legal and does nothing.